# PHP Сохранить текстовый файл

Tags: php

Задача с помощью POST запроса сохранить файл на сервере, сейчас делаю вот так:

Мой php:

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = './files'; //Directory to save the file that comes from client application.
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
}
?>
```

Отправляю POST запрос (на c#):

```
    System.Net.WebClient Client = new System.Net.WebClient();
     
    Client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
     
    byte[] result = Client.UploadFile("http://localhost/moysayt/upload.php", "POST", @"C:\autobuy.txt");
```

Файл успешно сохраняется в папке files.
Проблема в том что при одновременной отправке нескольких запросов на сохранение файлов (обращение не к одному и тому же файлу, файлы разные) я получаю request timeout сервер перестает работать, не открываеться даже localhost.
Как я понимаю мой upload.php не поддерживает паралельное сохрание файлов?
С php очень плохо знаком, как решить проблему - не знаю
Буду благодарен за любую помощь, спасибо!

Comment: А какой веб сервер? Вероятно, вы перегружаете ваш РНР или веб сервер, потому и падает все. Дело не в коде.

Comment: Принцип работы любого веб-сервера одинаков - они все работают в многопоточном режиме - точнее говоря поднимают копию себя же для каждого коннекта. Проверьте настройки веб-сервера - какое количество копий (childs) у Вас разрешено запускать.

Comment: @betrayer, windows server, iis, нагрузка на ЦП 4-5%, ОЗУ 20-30%
Изменил фай upload.php, добавил в него просто вывод текущего времени,  метод Client.UploadFile("/upload.php", "POST", @"C:\autobuy.txt");  теперь возвращает "500 Internal Server Error",что в принципе логично, сервер зависать перестал.

Comment: так включите трассировку failed requests и посмотрите что там у вас в ошибках. или локально с сервера зайдите, там более подробная инфа будет в ошибке помимо 500 кода

Comment: @teran, Трасировку включил, FailedReqLogFiles пустой, LogFiles показывает только успешные запросы.
Заметил что при добавлении кода создания текстового файла (из первого сообщения) потребление трафика растет до 30-40 Mbps и сервер падает, как только удаляю код - трафик падает до 1-2Mbps, канал 1GB

Comment: размер файла то какой грузите туда?

Comment: @teran, 30-100КБ, в минуту нужно выполнить примерно 50-70 запросов

Comment: гзипить-то не хотите? или пачками объединять и гзипить. (логика процесса что вообще и как делается мне не особо понятна, так что мысли вслух)

Comment: @teran, данный способом я сейчас отправляю на сервер логирование ошибок, понимаю все проблемы, но в данный момент изменить алгоритм работы не могу